# How to change the JDK for a Jenkins job?

Tags: java, jenkins

[image]I have imported the jenkins jobs from existing jenkins server from another machine. But the problem is, it has the JDK referenced as per the old machines and I want to change it to use the JDK configured in my new jenkins. But I am unable to find any way of doing this. So, please if you have come across this situation and found a way then please help me too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is a JDK dropdown in "job name" -> Configure in Jenkins web ui. It will list all JDKs available in Jenkins configuration.

As per @Derek comment below, n newer versions, you can find it in Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK.

Note that you need the "Overall/Administer" permission to manage Jenkins.

Comment: This, we will get while created new job but not while editing the existing job. I might be wrong as I have just started to configure jenkins.

Comment: It is also configurable in existing jobs. Open the Jenkins web ui, go into the job configuration - the JDK dropdown in one of the first configuration items.

Comment: Sorry, i am not able to find it. The config sections I have are:   
Advanced Project Options, Source Code Management, Build Triggers, Pre Steps, Build, Post Steps, Build Settings, Post-build Actions.

Comment: Is this a maven project? You should see "common" configs like Maven project name, Description etc right at the top of the Configuration page - this section includes JDK in my Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, It is Maven Project. You can have a look at snapshot I have updated in the question.

Comment: I am getting the JDK drop down in my old jenkins UI. Now sure why it is available in the new one.

Comment: Got it. I had error while configuring the JDK location in the manage jenkins section because of which it didn't have anything to show in the dropdown.

Comment: latest Jenkins version 2.7.4 is: Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK

Comment: Just a comment for explaining details: if you configured JDK correctly and you have more than one JDK configured in your Jenkins, you can easily find it in job-configure.

Comment: Is it possible the if there is only one jdk it does not show the option in project and take that one which is set?

Comment: It seems jdk option is not available while edit if there is only one jdk in Jenkins.

Answer (score 46):

**For existing jobs you're editing, the JDK drop-down choice may not be available if you've just added a single JDK config in the 'Configure System' Jenkins settings.**

However, it is available for new jobs.

**Surprisingly, if you add a second JDK config, it becomes available in an existing job too.**

This looks to me like a bug (tested in Jenkins ver. 1.629).

See a similar issue raised here: [JDK selection is hidden even when a JDK is configured](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10191)

Comment: yes that 's right, but even the JDK dropdown occurred, the build always get error for maven cannot find the java

Comment: still a problem in 2.107.3 ... just wasted 30mins of my life

Comment: The above workaround solved my issue.   Still an issue in 2.138.3

Comment: Exactly! I had to add another JDK in the Global Config section, and then it showed up in the job deployment config section. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems this is true. Job is working but no jdk option is available.

Answer (score 23):

Here is where you should configure in your job:

In JDK there is the combobox with the different JDK configured in your Jenkins.
[image: Job]

Here is where you should configure in the config of your Jenkins:

[image: Jenkins general config]

Comment: I am getting the JDK drop down in my old jenkins UI. Not sure why it is available in the new one

Comment: Are JDKs configured in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> JDK installations?

Comment: Got it. I had error while configuring the JDK location in the manage jenkins section because of which it didn't have anything to show in the dropdown.

Comment: There is no such **JDK** section.

Comment: The JDK section is in Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration now.

Answer (score 17):

Using latest Jenkins version 2.7.4 which is also having a bug for existing jobs.

1. Add new JDKs through Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK
   ** If you edit current job then JDK dropdown is not showing (bug)
2. Hit http://your_jenkin_server:8080/restart and restart the server
3. Re-configure job

Now, you should see JDK dropdown in "job name" -> Configure in Jenkins web ui. It will list all JDKs available in Jenkins configuration.

Comment: Restart was key, so this answer combined with the @nomis answer did the trick for me. (Using Jenkins v2.32.3)

Comment: This doesn't work for pipeline projects - so had to explicity reference JDK version in jenkinsfile

Answer (score 5):

Here is my experience with Jenkins version 1.636:
as long as I have only one "Install automatically" JDK configured in Jenkins JDK section, I don't see "JDK" dropdown in Job=>Configure section, 
but as soon as I added second JDK in Jenkins config, JDK dropdown appeared in Job=>Configure section with 3 options [(System), JDK1, JDK2]

Comment: This is similar to my experience with Jenkins 1.647, however in my case JDK1 was an explicitly named JDK. Only when I added a second did I get the option to specify the "JDK to be used for this project" and got the three options

Answer (score 4):

Hello it is possible set a new JDK in old job, if you use the Pipeline. You just write something like this:

```
pipeline{
 agent any
 tools{
     jdk 'deafault'
 }
 stages{ 
    stage('build'){
       ..............
       }
    } 
 } 
}
```

Where default is just the name that you give to the JDK when you config it in the Jenkins configuration Global System.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a multi-config (matrix) job, you do not have a JDK dropdown but need to configure the jdk as build axis.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with jobs

1 - if you have a job based in maven, Jenkins takes your default java configuration and you decide the compilation level in your POM.XML.

2 - if you have a free style job, in the  the configuration option of the job you can select the JDK that you want to use.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

For those who couldn't find this option. Install [JDK Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/jdk+parameter+plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (running Jenkins v2.303.1) and I needed to add new JDKs before I saw them in the project settings.

Go to "Manage Jenkins (in german: Jenkins verwalten)", then "Configuration of tools (in german: Konfiguration der Hilfsprogramme)" and there should be a section regarding "JDK". Here, you can manage your different java versions (whether to download or use local ones):
[image: Picture of JDK section]

After setting these JDKs I was able to choose which JDK version to use: [image: JDK choose option]

Answer (score 0):

you should only add this path to Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK

for java 11

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

for java 8

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64