# How to set the JDK version for the jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

We have a requirement that we need to set the JDK version to 1.8 from 1.7 for all the jobs ran during last 3 months.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.task.*

for (item in Hudson.instance.allItems){         
    if(item.name.contains("test")){   
      if(item.JDK != null){
        manager.listener.logger.println("test job are  : " + item.name); 
        manager.listener.logger.println("JDK : " + item.JDK);
        manager.listener.logger.println("\n =========== \n");
       }    
    }
}
```

With the above code, i am able to fethc the JDK version for all the Test jobs, in the below format.

```
 test job are  : jacoco_test  
 JDK : JDK[SUN-JDK-1.7]
 ============================
 test job are  :kps-batch-snapshot-test  
 JDK : JDK[IBM-JDK-8]
```

but i am not able to set them to  **IBM-JDK-8**.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Have look at this post it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810477/how-to-change-the-jdk-for-a-jenkins-job

Comment: Thnaks but I have already seen the post, it talks about changes from UI side, where as i am  looking from script side...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#setJDK(hudson.model.JDK)), it can be done using setJDK(). Try this:

```
item.JDK = Jenkins.instance.getJDK('IBM-JDK-8')
```

Comment: setJDK() is not available..  
'No signature of method: hudson.model.Hudson.setJDK() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [IBM-JDK-8]'

Comment: Have you added the line as it is described? It looks from your error message that you are trying to call setJDK() on another object. I have tried running this code in Jenkins 1.17 scriptConsole and it works just fine (changing manager...println to plain 'println').

Comment: @JoachimNilsson, I am getting **ERROR: Build step failed with exception
14:50:51 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class:** , can you please suggest what is wrong with this. I have provided valid imports in script as well.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya Probably a missing import statement

Comment: @joachimnilsson , import Jenkins.model.* is present in script

Comment: @AlpeshGediya - that is what is wrong then, Jenkins in upper-case in the package name. Use import jenkins.model.* (lowercase)

Comment: @AlpeshGediya - When you get this type of error in Groovy (No such property: NNN), it is an indication of that the NNN class/variable/whatever is not available so you should search for the error on the lines containing the exact text 'NNN'