# Making jenkins and maven use different java versions

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-3

I need to update Jenkins master to the newer version which requires java new version but my **jenkins** master machine has older java version.

All my build jobs on the master use maven which uses older java version.

So, if I upgrade java my builds will no longer work.So, is there is solution for this?

Comment: I'd advise that you upgrade all your Java JDKs to version 8.  All others have passed their support life.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't fix your builds? After all, they're _yours_.

Comment: Are you talking about running Jenkins with one version of Java and running individual jobs within Jenkins using a different version of Java?

Comment: @Esko I have around 300 builds.I don't want to fix them all.

Comment: @sisyphus you are right.I am talking about  running Jenkins with one version of Java and running individual jobs within Jenkins using a different version of Java

Comment: You can have multiple versions of Java on a single machine, and you can configure Jenkins to know about multiple installations of Java, with each job configured to use a different one. The java you use to run the Jenkins application needn't affect any of your jobs.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s05.html

Within Jenkins you can configure multiple different JDKs for you individual job builds. They're configured under the 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Configure System' page, in the 'JDK' section. Just install each different JDK on a different place in your filesystem, point Jenkins to it and then given it a name on this page.

For any individual job you can just tell it to use a specific version of the JDK, using the name configured above. Jenkins will set JAVA_HOME appropriately. [How to change the JDK for a Jenkins job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810477/how-to-change-the-jdk-for-a-jenkins-job)

After that, running Jenkins using the new JDK is matter of installing the new JDK in an appropriate place and modifying your startup to pick up that version of java.

Answer (score 1):

With lates Jenkins version, these settings are under `Global Tool Configuration` or short `/configureTools/`:
'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Global Tool Configuration' -> 'Add JDK'.