# Getting an error while integrating SonarQube with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I followed the SonarQube Jenkins integration tutorial from SonarQube official website. I am getting an error after building my project.

`[RetailerWebsite_releaseTestCodeDx] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins2\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\My_scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat" "SonarQube Scanner" -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://10.252.80.55:9000 -Dsonar.projectName=RetailerWebsite -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=Retailer-Website -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=D:\Builds\RetailerWebsite_releaseTestCodeDx
\Jenkins2\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\My_scanner\bin\..\jre was unexpected at this time.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 255`

Project Configuration
[image]
Global Configuration[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are victim of [this Jenkins bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11992): when using a JRE installed at a path that includes parentheses, Jenkins (on Windows) tries to execute an invalid command.

Workaround: install the JDK elsewhere, and use that one in your Job configuration (or Jenkins itself).

Comment: I didn't get it, could you please elaborate? I got your point my Jenkins is installed in ```Program Files (x86) ``` directory and JRE is under it. Where should I do the update?

Comment: How to do that is explained for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810477/how-to-change-the-jdk-for-a-jenkins-job)

Comment: Hi @HuguesM. I am also facing same issue, due stack exceeds, if possible can you guide on the below issue, link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203208/sonar-scanner-issue-in-jenkins)