# Can we upgrade to java 8 with jenkins 1.6.xx

Tags: java, jenkins

I actually don't want to upgrade Jenkins.
It is recommended to use java 8 with Jenkins 2.5.xx

Still I want to know if someone has done the other way around?
Keep Jenkins version same, i.e. 1.6.XX and upgrade the java to 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the JDK for a Jenkins job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810477/how-to-change-the-jdk-for-a-jenkins-job)

Comment: Thanks Pritam for replying, i want to change JDK, but its a specific JDK, which is intended for Jenkins 2.5.x and above.
I want to use my old jenkins, i.e. 1.6.x and use JDK8.

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you have reason to believe it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I do run Jenkins 1.6xx with the latest JDK8 without any issue.

And I execute job in Jenkins agents, with said job needing JDK8, also without issue.